# A Way to Add Text Before Your Hyperlink in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

Is there a way to add text before the hyperlink?

So for example:

> This section needs reworking. You can find the section HERE.

`HERE` would be the text replacement for the actual link. The actual text would read like this.

```
This section needs reworking. You can find the section =HYPERLINK("www.yourlink.com", "HERE").
```

When I try this is does not work, so I am thinking if there is a way it might use some different code.

Answer (score 8):

It's official. [This cannot be done](https://docs.google.com/document/preview?hgd=1&id=1x_qjPL5rmSuQWW57KcwB9lg3eiykKpd8dMEaQUZbWU8#heading=h.59og5slq1crb).

> Like the other types of data and cell formatting, links in spreadsheets must be assigned to an entire cell, you cannot have just part of the text inside a cell be hyperlinked.

The source document is linked to from [edutraining.googleapps.com](http://edutraining.googleapps.com/drive/chapter-3).

Comment: William, your link is broken. You have a good link?

Comment: The "Like other types of data and cell formatting" is  no longer true.  You can now apply character formatting (bold, italic, underline, etc) to any number of characters in a cell, rather than all characters.  The same "should" be true for hyperlinks, but isn't :-]

Comment: It's hard to believe it's 5 years on and such a crucial feature is still missing from Google Spreadsheets.

Comment: For me, all of a sudden, hyperlinks within a cell full of other text are suddenly behaving and looking like hyperlinks! But Sheets randomly decides when it can recognise them because other cells in the same column are still treating the hyperlinks that they contain as if they are plain text.

Answer (score -2):

That's how you do it, but you have an extra space.  It should be:
=HYPERLINK("www.yourlink.com","HERE")

I do this all the time with FB links:
=HYPERLINK("http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx","FB Link")

Comment: That's not what the OP is asking for.. please go through the FAQ (http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq) as well. This is not a usual forum site :)