# Rich text formatting in a Google Sheets cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format, microsoft-excel

**How is it possible to enable "rich text formatting" inside a single Google Sheets cell?**

I'd like to have a cell containing some text with both bold and non-bold content, words in italic, with some hypertext links, etc.

How to do this with Google Sheets?

---

Example: When I copy paste:

This is a test. This text is **bold** or *italic*.

into a Google Sheets cell, the formmating is lost: only italic is kept but *for the whole cell*.

As a comparison, when I copy/paste  it into an Excel cell, the formatting is ok:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rich-Text formatting is not an OPT in/out / turn on/off feature. It's always turned on. To use it:

1. Put the cell in edit mode
2. Type the text
3. Select the text part to apply bold, italics, color
4. Apply the desired format by using the Google Sheets toolbar or keyboard-shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> for bold, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> for italics, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to insert a link, etc.
5. Put the cell in display mode (press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, click the <kbd>Tab</kbd>, etc.)

Notes:

1. If copy-paste is not working and you aren't using Chrome it's very likely that format that is failing is an unsupported feature for the Operative System / web browser that you are using, if it's not working in Chrome stable channel, the it's very likely that it's a bug.
2. In Google Sheets cells, the Rich-Text formatting options are limited, <s>no in-in-line hyperlinks</s>, no in-line images.

Related

- [A Way to Add Text Before Your Hyperlink in Google Spreadsheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/24931/88163)
- [Is it possible to have plain text and a link in the same cell?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/83073/88163)

Resources

- [Edit & format a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/46973?hl=en)
- [Keyboard shortcuts for Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110?hl=en)
- [Work with links, bookmarks, section breaks, or page breaks](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/45893?hl=en)

Comment: It seems that you can't put a link https://example.com to a *specific part* of a cell, it's only for the whole cell, do you confirm?

Comment: Also can we insert images in the middle of the text (rich HTML content)? I don't think so, I think that image is either over cells, or in cell (but then it uses the full cell)

Comment: You can now make PARTS of a cell's text into a hyperlink - just select the text and hit `Ctrl-K`.

Comment: @Basj Answer updated

Comment: @RashaMatt Thanks :)