# Editing the second line in all cells

Tags: google-sheets, automation, google-sheets-cell-format

I am creating a sheet in which the first column has two lines of text in every row. How can I bold the second line only in all cells without doing it manually as I already created the sheet.

[image: This is what I want it to look like]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications](/tour "Web Apps Tour"). Consider [registering your account](/users/login "Login") to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. [Registering](/users/login "Login") is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/)

Answer (score 0):

I know that the only way to do this is by using **Google Apps Script** or the **Google Sheets API**, more specifically by using [Class RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value). You might look for Add-ons that have used these tools on the **Google Workspace Marketplace**. This could be accessed from the Google Sheets editor:

1. Open a spreadsheet in **Google Sheets**.
2. Click the **Extensions** menu, then **Get add-ons**.

To learn more, check out the Google Sheets help. To do this

1. Open a spreadsheet in **Google Sheets**.
2. Click the **Help** menu, then **Sheets Help** or **Training**.

You could create a **Google Apps Script** project bound to your spreadsheet:

1. Open a spreadsheet in **Google Sheets**.
2. Click the **Extensions** menu, then **Apps Script**.

To learn more, go to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

The **Google Sheets API** could be used on many programming platforms and languages. To start with it, you should create a **Google Cloud** project in the **Google Cloud Console**.

To learn more, go to https://developers.google.com/sheets/api.

### Related

- [Rich text formatting in a Google Sheets cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/136964/88163)